Error: when trying to import pipeline_pb2 from object_detection.protos
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2

 from google.protobuf import runtime_version as _runtime_version
ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime_version' from 'google.protobuf'

I am getting this error above.
Python version 3.10
Tensorflow 2.16.2
Pipeline 0.1.0
Also in my IDE (Pycharm), when I import from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2, "pipeline_pb2" is underlined in red and it says:

Cannot find reference 'pipeline_pb2' in 'init.py'

What can I try next?
